# Function to return different values C++

Tags: c++

I need to make a function,lets name it fun1, which will return 2 values. It will return `A` for every 10th time, else it will return `B`.

Then, in another function, lets call it fun2, I need to check 
`if(fun1=="A")
  return aVariableIneed;
else
  return bVariableIneed;`

Using a string/int/whatever function which returns value did not work for me, as it always needs a parameter, and returns one and only one. I think void is the way to go. I have thought about using arrays but I am not so sure about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `C#` tag relevant here?

Comment: A function does not need to have a parameter, although it will only have 0 or 1 returned values.  But your question is unclear-  are you having problems writing a function that returns "A" only every tenth time?  Or something else?

Comment: `A` and `B` should be the same type.

Comment: static, you are probably wanting to use static, within functions anyway. (It has many uses, depending on where it's used)

Comment: @RSahu: I don't think a union would be helpful. The OP wants a function that returns one value on some calls, and a different value on other calls. Presumably both values are of the same type.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I interpreted the question differently. I think he wants the function to return an object of type `A` every 10-th time. Otherwise, the function returns an object of type `B`.

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried that didn't work? It is very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @RSahu: I agree it needs more clarity, but in the code that calls the function he's comparing the value returned by the function for equality to `"A"` (ignoring the missing `()` on the function call). And he did refer to `A` and `B` as "two values", not two types.

Comment: @KeithThompson, Now that I have read the post again with more care, you are most likely right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pass by reference to return values in your parameters.

```
void fun1( int &firstReturnVal, int &secondReturnVal, int pass ) {
   firstReturnVal = ...; // will be viewable by caller
   secondReturnVal = ...; // will be viewable by caller
}

int main() {
   int a, b;
   fun1( a, b, 2 );
   std::cout << "return values: " << a << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is a WAAAY better way than what I posted. When he learns about memory management and speed, this will be better.

Answer (score 1):

" It will return A for every 10th time, else it will return B."

If you wanna return just one value at a time, but keep count of how many times the function was already called, what you're looking for is a static variable.
You can use this static variable that maintains its value in between the calls to count how many times the function was already called and then use an if-else statement to determine which one should be returned.

If you wanna return more than one value at a single time, there's no way to do that, except returning an array (which will return, really, only one element, the pointer to the array, but you could store as many elements as you want in that array and then retrieve them outside of the function)

Answer (score 1):

```
int fun1()
{
   static int times = 0;
   times++;
   if(times % 10 == 0)
   {
       //return 10 if on multiples of 10
       return 10;
   }

   //return something else.
   return 1;
}
```

For complex stuff, use else.

I think this is what you're after, but you may wanna review Static and anything that looks unfamiliar. Your school/tut/teacher only gives the bare minimum required to solve assignments, then teaches the "easy way" after, common practice

Comment: You forgot to increment `times`

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a strongly typed language, so the first thing you need to determine is whether "A" and "B" are the same type. You can't have a function that returns two different things without some shenanigans unless those things can be easily converted.

```
long f(bool condition) {
    if (condition)
        return 2.0; // type double
    else
        return 1; // type int
}
```

The compiler would probably generate warnings about this code, but it would compile. However, what is returned is determined by the function's finger print: this function returns `long`, so the 2.0 gets converted to 2 and the 2 gets converted from an int to a long.

```
int f(bool condition) {
    if (condition)
        return 1;
    else
        return "hello"; // illegal: no conversion possible
}
```

Next: Do these symbols you specified represent a character (`'A'`) a string (`"A"`) or a variable defined somewhere else and named *capital A* (`A`).

I can only assume, but it seems like you want a character, `'A'`. If you have some familiarity with other languages, such as Python, you might not realize that there's a big difference between *character A* and *string containing character A*, `'A' vs "A"`.

Depending how early you are in your course, it's probable that what you need is something like this:

```
int times = 0; // caveat: this value can become negative.
// caveat: this value can only hold positive numbers 0 thru 2^31

char fn1() {
    ++times;
    if (times < 10)
        return 'A';
    else {
        //times = 0; // reset for next time
        return 'B';
    }
}
```

We don't know for sure whether the `times = 0` is needed. If it was, I would expect the task to be "every 10th time" rather than just "and the tenth time".

Now we can write `fn2`.

```
int fn2() {
    if (fn1() == 'A') {
        return aVariableINeed;
    } else {
        return bVariableINeed;
    }
}
```

and we can put all of this together into a program like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int aVariableINeed = 10;
int bVariableINeed = 20;

int times = 0;

char fn1() {
    ++times;
    if (times < 10)
        return 'A';
    else {
        return 'B';
    }
}

int fn2() {
    if (fn1() == 'A') {
        return aVariableINeed;
    } else {
        return bVariableINeed;
    }
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << fn2() << "\n";
    }
}
```

This is, however, not healthy, modern C++. This is "what your professor might be looking for at your stage".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

// Returns "first" for the first N times and then returns "second.
// Thus Countdown('A', 'B', 10) returns 'A' 9 times and then 'B' the 10th.
class Countdown
{
    char m_first, m_second;
    size_t m_times = 0;  // How many times we've displayed
public:
    Countdown(char first_, char second_, size_t times_) noexcept
        : m_first(first_), m_second(second_)
        , m_times(std::max(times_, size_t(1)) - 1)
        {
        }

    char first() const { return m_first; }
    char second() const { return m_second; }

    char next() noexcept {
        if (m_times > 0) {
            --m_times;
            return m_first;
        }
        return m_second;
    }
};

int fn2(Countdown& countdown, int aVariable, int bVariable) {
    return (countdown.next() != countdown.second())
        ? aVariable : bVariable;
}

int main()
{
    Countdown countdown('A', 'B', 10);
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << fn2(countdown, 10, 20) << "\n";
    }
}
```